# Error in code at -> when(list.size()).thenReturn(10) while running Unit Test

Tags: spring, mockito

The errors are as follows:
The method thenReturn(Dimension) in the type OngoingStubbing is not applicable for the arguments (int)
The method size() from the type Component is deprecated

```
 @Test
 public void Test() {

    List list = mock(List.class);
    when(list.size()).thenReturn(10);
    assertEquals(10, list.size());

}
```

Comment: You've imported java.awt.List instead of java.util.List. (And I hope you realize this test doesn't do anything useful)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks . Working fine now

Comment: @JBNizet you should've posted it as an answer. I think this snippet is from 28minutes udemy course of mockito

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are importing `import java.awt.List;` instead of `import java.util.List;`